# How can I make svn command line client to forget the login credentials on windows (sliksvn)?

Tags: svn, command-line, authentication

After having checked out once the repository to a folder, the svn command line client remembers the username and password (along with the repository url?). So, 2 questions arise:

- is there a way to make it stop remembering the login info (and ask user/pass every time)?
- is there a way to make it 'forget' the current login info (to delete the credentials already stored).

Thanks!

Comment: To answer the other question, the credentials are stored per 'realm'. IIRC this is a combination of server and administrator set string, that's also displayed in the login box. See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch06s02.html#svn-ch-6-sect-2.2 for details.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

To make it forget the current credentials:
The credentials are cached somewhere in `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth` Check the files in there to decide where to check, or remove all the files.

To make it stop remembering the login info:

1. Edit `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config`.
2. Set `store-auth-creds=no`

Comment: The files storing the actual credentials on my system were in `%APPDATA%\Subversion\config\svn.simple\[hex filename]`. Deleting those files caused `svn` to ask again.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz At the moment the correct path seems to be `%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple\[hex filename]`

Answer (score 27):

On Linux systems you need to remove the *~/.subversion/auth* directory to forget the existing authentication details.

In the *~/.subversion/servers* file set **store-passwords** value to **no**

On Windows Systems remove the "%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth" directory.  Don't forget the quotes as generally %APPDATA% is in "Documents and Settings" path.

Answer (score 9):

The SVN client should accept a `--no-auth-cache` option for this.

Answer (score 5):

```
 rm -Rf ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple/* && security delete-generic-password -a ACCOUNTNAMETOREMOVE
```

This will remove the cached credentials stored by SVN as well as the keychain entry in OSX.

Comment: what does `security` call for ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is for Windows, but I found it when looking on my Mac. So just in case someone else comes along in the future like I did, here's what worked for me. OSX 10.9 with SVN version 1.7.10

svn switch http://svn.repository.url --username new_user

and it worked for me.

Comment: That'll do a sneaky `svn up` for you too.

Answer (score 0):

or to target places you don't remember where you dumped your creds...

locate svn.simple | xargs grep -il username | xargs rm -fv

"Nuke the entire 'creds' from orbit. It's the only way to be sure" - Ripley